# Cannot export Apple ID from Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode9

I'm trying to export my Apple ID from within Xcode 9.

The error message that appears says:

> **Couldn’t communicate with a helper application.**
>
> Try your operation again. If that fails, quit and relaunch the application and try again.

I did restart everything and also recreated my certificate - without luck.

My OS is macOS High Sierra.

How to solve this?

Comment: I "solved" this with XCode 9.4-beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, but it was resolved when updating to Xcode 9.3.1.

Answer (score 3):

You can run this code in Terminal, and then restart Xcode.

```
xcrun git config --global user.email your@email.com
xcrun git config --global user.name your name
```

Comment: thanx! finally i can see git changes and also open authors/comparison mode. the problem appeared after update to `Xcode 10.2.1 (10E1001)` and your answer helped. cheers :)